# Multiple subdomains resolving to one domain?

Tags: subdomain

I'm trying to host an application, but allow the customer to use their own sub domain so that it does not confuse their own customers.

So for example, by application would run on app.mydomain.com, but my customer would access it via their own subdomain (app.somedomain.com and/or app.anotherdomain.com).

Is this even possible?

I know it is possible to use wildcards for subdomains in Apache (i.e All requests on *.mydomain.com), but can you use wildcards for the whole domain with shared hosting?

(Possibly relevant information: my application is hosted on media temple and uses Apache)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mod_rewrite](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) to translate requests from one domain into another, however, take care that you get the SSL case right if that's in the cards. Modern browsers warn when the SSL certificate doesn't match the domain in question, ie they visit app.somedomain.com and get a certificate valid for app.mydomain.com instead.